# Случайный стиль после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, css

Надо чтобы после перезагрузки страницы у всех блоков менялся `border-left: 35px solid #00f;` рандом. 
У одного может быть top у другого left у третьего right  и так далее. Помогите пожалуйста

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
}

.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle__img,
.circle:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.circle__img {
  object-fit: cover;
}

.circle:before {
  content: '';
  border-left: 35px solid #00f;
  border-radius: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <img class="circle__img" src="https://www.vbetnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Jurgen-Klopp.png" alt="">
</div>


<div class="circle">
  <img class="circle__img" src="https://www.vbetnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Jurgen-Klopp.png" alt="">
</div>



<div class="circle">
  <img class="circle__img" src="https://www.vbetnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Jurgen-Klopp.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого вы можете использовать массивы, т.е. сохраняя в них рандомные стили, которые в дальнейшем будете использовать:

`let array = ['border-left', 'border-right', 'border-top', 'border-bottom']`

А потом, генерировать случайное число в пределах 0 и длины вашего массива. После чего обращаться к элементу массива по случайно сгенерированному индексу. А значение дальше используйте.

Comment: похожие вопросы [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915096/get-random-item-from-javascript-array) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const classes = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'pink', 'yellow', 'black'];
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.circle');

elements.forEach(element => 
    element.classList.add(
        classes[~~(classes.length * Math.random())]
    )
);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
}

.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.circle__img,
.circle:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.circle__img {
  object-fit: cover;
}

.circle:before {
  content: '';
  border-style: solid;
  border-color:  #00f;
  border-left-width: 35px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.circle.red:before { border-color: red; }
.circle.blue:before { border-color: blue; }
.circle.green:before { border-color: green; }
.circle.pink:before { border-color: pink; }
.circle.yellow:before { border-color: yellow; }
.circle.black:before { border-color: black; }
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <img class="circle__img" src="https://www.vbetnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Jurgen-Klopp.png" alt="">
</div>
<div class="circle">
  <img class="circle__img" src="https://www.vbetnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Jurgen-Klopp.png" alt="">
</div>
<div class="circle">
  <img class="circle__img" src="https://www.vbetnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Jurgen-Klopp.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант на jQuery.

```js
$('.demo .circle').each(function(){ // Перебераем каждый элемент
  let border = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4); // рандомное число
  switch(border) { // Выводим свои значения
    case 0: border = 'left'; break;
    case 1: border = 'top'; break;
    case 2: border = 'right'; break;
    case 3: border = 'bottom'; break;
  }
  // Присваиваем блоку новый стиль
  $(this).css('border-'+border, 'var(--border-style)');
});
```

```css
.demo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}

.demo .circle {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  /* Сам стиль прописан в CSS переменной */
  --border-style: 10px solid #07f;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.demo .circle:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.demo .circle > img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="demo">
  <div class="circle">
    <img src="https://www.vbetnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Jurgen-Klopp.png">
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <img src="https://www.vbetnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Jurgen-Klopp.png">
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <img src="https://www.vbetnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Jurgen-Klopp.png">
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <img src="https://www.vbetnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Jurgen-Klopp.png">
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <img src="https://www.vbetnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Jurgen-Klopp.png">
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <img src="https://www.vbetnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Jurgen-Klopp.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: этот код не поддерживается на IE11 ,  а мне надо чтобы и там работал